# Gradle permits two files with the same name in zip archive

Tags: gradle

I have a gradle task, `buildZip`, that places the contents of two directories into a single directory. Both directories each contain a single file with the same name, `myFile.txt`, but their contents are different. This is the original directory structure:

```
foo/
├── bar/
│   └── myFile.txt    # 10kB
└── baz/
    └── myFile.txt    # 20kB
```

The Gradle task places both files into the root directory of the archive:

```
task buildZip(type: Zip) {
    archiveName 'myArchive.zip'
    includeEmptyDirs false

    from('foo/bar') {
      include 'myFile.txt'
    }
    from('foo/baz') {
      include 'myFile.txt'
    }
}
```

I would assume that the second `from...include` would overwrite the first `myFile.txt`. Instead, this is the structure of the resulting archive:

```
myArchive.zip
├── myFile.txt    # 10kB
└── myFile.txt    # 20kB
```

This results in some strange behavior:

- When I open the archive and change the name of one `myFile.txt` to `myFile.txt.bkup` (via WinZip), both files change names accordingly.
- Both files report their original sizes (10kB and 20kB), but their contents are identical - specifically, that of the latter `myFile.txt` from `foo/baz`.

Why doesn't Gradle automatically overwrite files in the archive if a file with that name already exists? Why is it possible to create two files of the same name in the same directory without overwriting one?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this is the behavior of `org.apache.tools.zip.ZipOutputStream` (which gradle uses to create zip archives). At this class first zip entry headers are written, I think thats the reason zip file looks like it contains 2 files. And when it writes actual files' stream, then it overrides previous file's content(because of the same name.)

[Gradle Zip](https://github.com/gradle/gradle/blob/master/subprojects/core/src/main/java/org/gradle/api/tasks/bundling/Zip.java)

[ZipOutputStream](https://github.com/apache/ant/blob/c5e87fec833258dd0fbb228355fb1cc8d3dbc720/src/main/org/apache/tools/zip/ZipOutputStream.java#L1053)

Comment: Looking at the code, it seems that while the original file stream *is* overwritten, the buffer size is not affected, even though the content is changed. That would explain why the files appear identical but still report their original file size. Would that make this a bug, or is there a reason for this behavior?

Comment: @Bucket I am not %100 sure, but I think this is related to internal of zip file format. OutputStream probably writes the files bytes as it gets flushed.(that is probably overwrite the previous file with same name) In the specification search for 4.3.7 section (where local file headers are explained. )   https://www.loc.gov/preservation/digital/formats/digformatspecs/APPNOTE%2820120901%29_Version_6.3.3.txt